# Tweaking binary serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, binary

I have a in a database a base64 string containing a binary serialized object.

In the object, there is a string property I want to tweak.

Is it possible, without knowing the actual type to "fix" a string ? The length of the string will change, that's why I don't want to simply replace the value.

In a more general way, what is the structure of a binary serialized object ?

Comment: do you know what serializer was used? BinaryFormatter, protobuf-net?

Comment: I guess it's BinaryFormatter, but I'm not sure (but as the software has not protbuf dll in its folder, I'm confident).

Comment: I'd rather refer to experts like Marc Gravell on this subject, but most likely, it can't be easily done and you'll break the object. Here's the link to the format spec: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236844%28PROT.10%29.aspx

Comment: Maybe I should take another approach: find the actual object (the binary seems to include some type names), deserialize it, fix my property, reserialize it. thanks for the link

Comment: I find that I was wrong. The actual serializer is [objectstateformatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.objectstateformatter.aspx). Maybe this structure will be simpler to decode